# PHP script gives null for MySQL query, possibly because of TVF?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server-2008

```
<?php
        include_once 'DbConnect.php';

        global $connect;
        global $io;
        global $myData;
        global $data;
        global $Throughput1;
        global $Throughput2;
        global $TimeStamp;
        global $Amount;
        global $Amount2;
        global $Time;
        global $Time2;
        global $record;

        $io = 0;
        $myData = "
                    Drop table tempdb.dbo.#temp
                    Drop table tempdb.dbo.#temp2

                    declare @fqnLine1Throughput varChar(400); 
                    declare @fqnLine2Throughput varChar(400); 
                    declare @parameter2Line1 varChar(4000);
                    declare @parameter2Line2 varChar(4000);  
                    declare @server varChar(200);
                    declare @timeStart datetime;
                    declare @timeEnd datetime;

                    set @fqnLine1Throughput = 'MyEnterprise.Trident.Sites.Carrollton.Documents.Charts.Line 1.Throughput'; 
                    set @fqnLine2Throughput = 'MyEnterprise.Trident.Sites.Carrollton.Documents.Charts.Line 2.Throughput';
                    set @parameter2Line1 = '.Throughput';
                    set @parameter2Line2 = '.Throughput';
                    set @timeStart = DATEADD(minute,-10,GETDATE());
                    set @timeEnd = GETDATE();
                    set @server = 'car-ftvp';

                    SELECT CONVERT(VARcHAR(20),localTimeStamp, 108) as Time, valueAsFloat as Amount, shortName as ThroughputLine1 
                    Into tempdb.dbo.#temp
                    From dbo.History(@fqnLine1Throughput, @parameter2Line1, @timeStart, @timeEnd, @server)

                    SELECT  CONVERT(VARcHAR(20),localTimeStamp, 108) as Time2, valueAsFloat as Amount2, shortName as ThroughputLine2
                    Into tempdb.dbo.#temp2
                    From dbo.History(@fqnLine2Throughput, @parameter2Line2, @timeStart, @timeEnd, @server)

                    Select Time, Amount, Amount2 from tempdb.dbo.#temp
                    Inner Join  tempdb.dbo.#temp2 on ThroughputLine1 = ThroughputLine2
                    Order by Time
                    " ;

        $record = odbc_exec($connect, $myData);

        while(odbc_fetch_row($record))
        {
            $TimeStamp = odbc_result($record, "Time");
            $Throughput1 = odbc_result($record, "Amount");
            $Throughput2 = odbc_result($record, "Amount2");


            $data[$io] = array($TimeStamp, $Throughput1, $Throughput2);
            $io = $io+1;    
        }
        echo $data;
        echo json_encode($data);
        odbc_close($connect);
?>
/*
```

So I am running this script from a javascript file, but I cannot seem to comprehend why I am  getting a response of null. In sql I can run the same query and get a table that has all the values I want, but the same code gives null from php.

dbo.history is also a tabled value function

I cannot provide my DbConnect file due to privacy

Comment: Check the server logs what caused the HTTP 500 error.

Comment: sorry i figured that out, i edited my question so it addresses a different problem

Comment: `echo $data` is pointless. `$data` is an array. it'll only ever print the literal word `Array`.

Comment: Do you get any results? Dump the variable `$record` with `var_dump()` and see if you get anything. Also a comment on php.net is stating you might need to use `odbc_fetch_row($record, 0);` before the while loop.

Comment: @AliAslam first you drop #temp and #temp2 but you don't create them again. how the data can be inserted if there is no table.